# формат суммы в fastreport

Tags: fastreport

не получается передать значение типа Float в Memo.

Значение присваетвается тогда, когда оно стринговое. А мне нужен Float что, бы поставить формат для для этого значения %2.2n

Вот исходник...

```
procedure MyMemoOnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
var    cend : double;    
begin
  cend := SysMemo1.value -SysMemo2.value;
  if  cend >= 0 then
     MyMemoD.text := floattostr(cend)
  else
     MyMemoD.text := '0';                                            
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать функцию `Format`.

```
MyMemoD.Text := Format('%2.2n', [cend]);
```